# Finding that a two variable limit does not exist trouble: $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{y^2 \sin^2 x}{x^4 + y^4}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have

$$ \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{y^2 \sin^2 x}{x^4 + y^4} $$

I've tried setting $y= 0, x=0, y=mx, y=x$, and lots of other things but because of the $\sin$ I keep getting a limit of zero. How do you show this doesn't exist?

Comment: Use the Taylor approximation, $\sin x = x$  Now, this won't prove that a limit does exist, but it is quick to prove that a limit does not exist.  Assume $x = ky$  Show that this limit depends on $k.$  This suggests that as you approach $0$ on different paths you have different values for $f(x,y)$ near $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\;y=x\;$ you already have it:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin^2x}{2x^4}=\frac12\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2=\frac12\neq0$$

Comment: Thank you. Until I looked at at it set out like that I forgot about the whole sin x over x equals 1 thing.

Answer (score 1):

As you say: if you let $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ your answer will be 0. If you let $y = x$, however, you get
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2 \sin^2(x)}{x^4 + x^4}
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{2x^2}
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation*}